# Eclipse for C++ - debugger not stopping at breakpoints

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

So I've seen some similar threads, but none had a fix for me.

My debugger is not stopping at breakpoints for some reason. I can set the breakpoint, and it shows as a breakpoint in the debugging perspective, but the debugger doesn't stop when I hit 'resume'. It means I need to manually step into where I need to go. Very inconvenient.

Also: Ignore all breakpoints is NOT set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved this. It was a matter of setting Eclipse to run "as Administrator". Damn windows.

Comment: You have to wait two days before it will let you. I solved it about 20 minutes after I posted.

Comment: Life saver. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Running under Ubuntu 18.04LTS in a VirtualBox VM.
This answer pertains to Eclipse PTP.

By default, double clicking on the left margin was adding PTP Breakpoints (I am not familiar with PTP debugging).
Those apparently do not make debugging stop.
I *right-clicked on a breakpoint* -> *Breakpoint Types* -> *C/C++ Breakpoints*, and it started inserting this other "usual" type of breakpoints.

You can tell one from the other, as they are indicated with large green vs. small purple circles.